# <lightning:select> limit height?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css

Is it possible to mention the number of options to display in .

```
<lightning:select>
   <option>option 1</option>
   <option>option 2</option>
   <option>option 3</option>
   <option>option 4</option>
   <option>option 5</option>
   <option>option 6</option>
   <option>option 7</option>
   <option>option 8</option>
   <option>option 9</option>
   <option>option 10</option>
 </lightning:select>
```

I need to display only 5 options to display to see other options i need to scroll.

Comment: That is possible with `multiselect="true"`

Comment: can you give more detail?

Comment: It's like that attribute will show you multiple options and the user will be able to select multiple options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use `lightning:select` (at least out of the box) to achieve what you are trying. The component always displays as drop down and that you will need to click on the component to render to view/select all of the options.

You can though achieve this using standard HTML [`select`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag and using the `size` attribute as below.

```
<select size="5">
    <option>option 1</option>
    ....
    <option>option 10</option>
</select>
```

And it renders as:

[image]

Comment: I need drop down. If i click drop down then only i need options like this.

Comment: There’s no way that I know of that you can control this behavior. I don’t know if it can be done using custom css or not.